# Google sheets : remove data from multiple columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to clean a file by removing specific values from different columns.
I have no problems doing it from one column but if I add the same script with a different column and run the two script the values are not removed correctly.

I am pretty new to this so my scripting might be wrong. Is there a better way to do this? Or a mistake I made?

```
    function clean() {

  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var deleteSelectedRows = removeThenSetNewVals();
  var runTime = (new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000;
  Logger.log("Runtime is: " + runTime + " seconds");
};

function removeThenSetNewVals(){
  
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var pattern = new RegExp("value1|value2");
var columnToSearch = 5;
var newRangeVals = range.getValues().filter(r => r[0] && !pattern.exec(r[columnToSearch]))  
range.clearContent();
var numRows = newRangeVals.length;
var newRange = sheet.getRange(1,1, numRows, newRangeVals[0].length).setValues(newRangeVals);
var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
sheet.deleteRows(numRows + 1, maxRows - numRows);
};

function clean2() {

  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var deleteSelectedRows = removeThenSetNewVals2();
  var runTime = (new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000;
  Logger.log("Runtime is: " + runTime + " seconds");
};

function removeThenSetNewVals2(){
  
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var pattern = new RegExp("Value1|Value3");
var columnToSearch = 2;
var newRangeVals = range.getValues().filter(r => r[0] && !pattern.exec(r[columnToSearch]))  
range.clearContent();
var numRows = newRangeVals.length;
var newRange = sheet.getRange(1,1, numRows, newRangeVals[0].length).setValues(newRangeVals);
var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
sheet.deleteRows(numRows + 1, maxRows - numRows);
};
```

Comment: just add the second column check to your `.filter()` - `.filter(r => r[0] && !pattern.exec(r[columnToSearch_1]) && !pattern.exec(r[columnToSearch_2]))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about if the values are different in the 2 columns ? I should have done that in my example (changed now)

Comment: You can make several patterns - for each column a different pattern

Comment: I do not really know how to do that, (this is only my second script), do you have any example I can use ?
It means I also have to remove the "var columnToSearch=" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all the checks in one `.filter()` method

```
function removeThenSetNewVals(){  
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1'),
      range = sheet.getDataRange(),
      maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows(),
      srchCol_1 = 2,
      srchPatt_1 = new RegExp("Value1|Value2"),
      srchCol_2 = 5,
      srchPatt_2 = new RegExp("Value1|Value3"),      
      newRangeVals = range.getValues().filter(r => r[0] && !srchPatt_1.exec(r[srchCol_1]) && !srchPatt_2.exec(r[srchCol_2])),
      numRows = newRangeVals.length;  
  range.clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(1,1, numRows, newRangeVals[0].length).setValues(newRangeVals);
  sheet.deleteRows(numRows + 1, maxRows - numRows);
}
```

and it might be better to replace `pattern.exec(string)` with `pattern.test(string)`?

Comment: Thank you very much Sergey !